# abbreviation of units of measure: 'hours' vs. 'minutes'

Tags: abbreviations

The abbreviation for ‘hours’ is hrs. 
The one for "Minute" is 'min'. It is a unit of measure, which have standard abbreviations, and they do not change in plural nor have a final period. So, the correct abbreviation for minute(s) is "min".
My question is: why this discrepancy and not 'hr' in line with 'min'?

Comment: It's common in both time and positioning for minutes and seconds to abbreviate minutes with an apostrophe ('single quote') and seconds with a quote ("double quote"); In ISO and similar time formatting it's typically colon-joined "hh:mm:ss" eg ":12:43" and "01:02:03". With and without padding and omissions, providing all the colons are included it communicates clearly. The Date `toISOString` method in browsers prints "2021-07-16T17:36:58.609Z" using this convention.

Answer (score 30):

What you have shown are ***common*** abbreviations: whether they are ***standard*** abbreviations depends on what you mean by *standard*. Officially, in this context, *standard* refers to abbreviations that have been officially set out by a national or international body.

I suspect you are wrong in stating that ***hrs*** is 'standard' for *hours*, while ***min*** is standard for *minute(s)*. It probably depends who wrote it. I would say that all of the following are *commonly used* abbreviations:

> hour(s): h, hr, hrs
>   minute(s): m, min, mins

Answer (score 15):

Standard units of measure have standard abbreviations. The hour and minute are not standard units (the standard unit is the second, symbol **s**), and consequently their abbreviations are not entirely standardised.

Note that where *hour* **is** used as a unit, for example in kilowatt-hour, it does have a standard symbol, **h**. The symbol for kilowatt-hour is **kWh**.

Note too that there is a difference between *symbol* (which is standardised) and *abbreviation* (which is not).

Comment: FWIW, I work for a large educational publisher and our house style is to abbreviate "hours" as "h". We see "hr" or "hrs" all the time, and we will always change it to "h"

Comment: While the minute and the hour are not standard SI units, they are accepted for use together with SI units. The standard symbol for minutes is min while for hours it is h. See here: https://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/table6.html